# How to calculate employment year based on hire date in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, database-design, date-arithmetic, calculation

Thanks for reading this (in advance)..

I have a database that contains a table showing an Employee's Hire Date, and I'm trying to create a PTO table using a Query that calculates Sick Days based on the following criteria:

16 days per working year

If the Hire Date is *for eg.* 7/7/2016, then an employee has 16 sick days to use between 7/7/2016 and 7/6/2017. At 7/7/2017, the employee once again has 16 days.

I'm trying to come up with the best way to calculate this information where I don't have to manually go in and change the new year for that employee each time he completes a year. (Too many records to manually change)

I considered using the DateAdd() function but it feels extreme or... maybe not the best method to go about doing this. I imagine I have to create a new column to list the new start date for each year (on each employee) but I can't figure out what the BEST calculation would be for it to automatically update each employee per year.

Not to mention, this would only apply to "active" employees as you need to be working for at least 3 months for you to have sick or vacation days....

I've been stressing my head for the past 2 hours looking through all possible formula to find something that I could use... Most of it reverts to me doing something manually each time..

Any ideas are so appreciated (you have no idea).

Comment: What *exactly* are you trying to calculate?  The start and end dates of the current employment year? So, do you need a formula that, with your example, on "today" would give the start/end dates of 7/7/2017 to 7/6/2018 for that employee? It would be helpful if you gave an example of the data you're working with, as well as an example of the expected outcome.

Comment: If it makes you feel any better, what you're describing is *exactly* what got me first started in Access.,,  hehe  PTO's and Sick Days, LWOPs and NCNS ...  Too bad I can't just send you that database.  It was a learning curve, that's for sure, but I didn't have [so] either.  As for your comment about `DATEADD` being "too extreme", I'm not sure what you mean by that, but "correct way" is "whatever way works"..  (And yes, it will probably involve that function.)

Comment: @ashleedawg Okay, I am trying to "reset" the amount of sick days each employee has based on their employment year
For example:
Employee A was hired on 7/7/2016 and his employment year completes 7/7/2017 so at 7/7/2017, Employee A receives 16 sick days again, and at 7/7/2018, 7/7/2019 and so on... 

(sorry prematurely hit enter)

Comment: Also yes, I'm so happy StackOverflow exists now.. I've been searching all over the internet to figure this out but I'm getting a headache haha

Up to now, this is what I figure will be done... Creating a new table that tracks the employee PTO days:

{EmpID
AllottedSick
AllotedVacation
StartingYearSick
StartingYearVacation
RemainingSick
RemainingVacation}

The two I need to calculate, or figure out are the StartingYearSick/Vacation which will be "reset" to the alloted values each year.

Comment: I understand that part - but what I don't know is what you want to *do* with this date. I'll put it this way: if you had a query that told you how many sick days each employee had used & had left this year, would that solve the problem?  Before you answer that, the requirement would be that you have a table with a list of each employees hire date, and another table with a list of each sick day that the employee has used.

Comment: If you have it setup properly, there's no need to "reset" anything, ever, the query will always show the current sick day status for each employee, based on the current date

Comment: It's pretty much impossible to walk you through the whole process online, but the first thing you would need (after having the tables i mentioned setup) is a query that calculates each employee's "current employment year", based on today's date. It might be easier for you to dump all the data into Excel and get the formulas figured out there, and then it will be a lot easier to get it working in Access

Comment: Okay. I have the table that will store how many sick days each employee has used. (PTOTbl) And I have each employee's hire date (EmpEmploymentInfoTbl). While constructing the form to enter into PTOTbl, I wanted it to show the Balance of sick days for the employee (or balance of vacation days) and that's what started this mess lol.

Calculating the current employment year is where I'm stumped, but will do as you've advised and see if I can come up with something. Thanks!

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have much time right now, but using Excel as an example (and I hope you know Excel quite well before getting into doing this kind of stuff in a DB...) .... Put a list of start dates in Column A.  In B1 enter: `=IF(DATE(YEAR(NOW()),MONTH(A1),DAY(A1))>TODAY(),DATE(YEAR(NOW())-1,MONTH(A1),DAY(A1)),DATE(YEAR(NOW()),MONTH(A1),DAY(A1)))` and in C1: `=DATE(YEAR(B1)+1,MONTH(A1),DAY(A1))-1` and fill down the list.

Comment: ...That give you "current employment year." Study those formulas so you see how they work, it's actually quite simple.  Those formulas (with slight modifications, like how Access formulas don't start with `=`) could be used as criteria for an Access query: you want to **count** how many sick days each employee has used, **where** the sick_date is >= (the start of the employment year) and is also < (the end of the employment year)  If you're having trouble you may want to dump "all" of the data into Excel and get it all working there first. (Excel help is also more readily available)

Comment: You have ended my headache... Thank you so much. The answer seems so obvious now, and that makes me feel silly haha. But glad to have the answer. Thanks again. Wish I could give you a billion ratings. Sorry for taking up your time!

Comment: Yeah, I guess I just wasn't thinking outside my range of "hire month" and "hire date". It never occurred to me to use the current year as a base point, and it makes me feel really ridiculous haha.

Comment: :) Thinking outside of the box gets easier with practice.  It's usually the simplest tasks that I waste the most time on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Excel as an example, put a list of start dates in `Column A`.

In **`B1`** enter:

```
=IF(DATE(YEAR(NOW()),MONTH(A1),DAY(A1))>TODAY(),
    DATE(YEAR(NOW()),MONTH(A1),DAY(A1)),
    DATE(YEAR(NOW()),MONTH(A1),DAY(A1)))
```

In **`C1`** enter:

```
=DATE(YEAR(B1)+1,MONTH(A1),DAY(A1))-1
```

...and fill down the list.

That give you "`current employment year`" for each employee. Study those formulas so you see how they work, it's actually quite simple.

Those formulas (with slight modifications, like how Access formulas don't start with =) could be used as criteria for an Access query: you want to count how many sick days each employee has used, where:

```
sick_date  >= (the start of the employment year) AND
sick_date < (the end of the employment year)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to go via Excel for this.

First, create a query that lists your employees' work years:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    PersonID, 
    DateAdd("yyyy", 10 * Abs([Deca].[id] Mod 10) + Abs([Uno].[id] Mod 10),[HireDate]) AS YearStart, 
    IIf([LeaveDate] >= DateAdd("yyyy", 1, [YearStart]),DateAdd("d", -1, DateAdd("yyyy", 1 ,[YearStart])), [LeaveDate]) AS YearEnd
FROM 
    Personer, 
    MSysObjects AS Uno, 
    MSysObjects AS Deca
WHERE 
    DateAdd("yyyy", 10 * Abs([Deca].[id] Mod 10) + Abs([Uno].[id] Mod 10), [HireDate]) < [LeaveDate];
```

Save this as *qPersonYear*. Output will be like:

```
PersonID    YearStart   YearEnd
05  2000-04-18  2001-04-17
05  2001-04-18  2002-03-31
07  2000-11-01  2001-10-31
07  2001-11-01  2002-10-31
07  2002-11-01  2003-10-31
07  2003-11-01  2004-10-31
07  2004-11-01  2005-10-31
07  2005-11-01  2006-10-31
07  2006-11-01  2007-10-31
07  2007-11-01  2008-10-31
07  2008-11-01  2009-04-30
10  2001-12-01  2002-11-30
10  2002-12-01  2003-11-30
10  2003-12-01  2004-11-30
10  2004-12-01  2005-11-30
10  2005-12-01  2006-11-30
10  2006-12-01  2007-11-30
10  2007-12-01  2008-11-30
10  2008-12-01  2009-11-30
10  2009-12-01  2010-05-31
2   2000-11-01  2001-09-09
8   2001-04-01  2001-10-31
```

Create another query, *qPersonSickDate*, to retrieve the sick days.

The only fields needed are PersonID and SickDate.

Finally, create a query to count the sickdays:

```
SELECT 
    qPersonYear.PersonID, 
    qPersonYear.YearStart, 
    qPersonYear.YearEnd, 
    Count(qPersonSickDate.SickDate) AS SickDays
FROM 
    qPersonYear 
LEFT JOIN 
    qPersonSickDate 
    ON qPersonYear.PersonID = qPersonSickDate.PersonID
WHERE 
    qPersonSickDate.SickDate Between [YearStart] And [YearEnd] 
GROUP BY 
    qPersonYear.PersonID, 
    qPersonYear.YearStart, 
    qPersonYear.YearEnd;
```

and, voilà, you have your complete and sanitised output:

```
PersonID    YearStart   YearEnd SickDays
05  2000-04-18  2001-04-17  8
07  2000-11-01  2001-10-31  2
07  2001-11-01  2002-10-31  6
07  2002-11-01  2003-10-31  4
07  2003-11-01  2004-10-31  6
07  2004-11-01  2005-10-31  1
07  2005-11-01  2006-10-31  1
07  2006-11-01  2007-10-31  4
07  2007-11-01  2008-10-31  5
07  2008-11-01  2009-04-30  1
10  2001-12-01  2002-11-30  8
10  2002-12-01  2003-11-30  11
10  2003-12-01  2004-11-30  6
10  2004-12-01  2005-11-30  6
10  2005-12-01  2006-11-30  8
10  2006-12-01  2007-11-30  4
10  2007-12-01  2008-11-30  3
10  2008-12-01  2009-11-30  1
2   2000-11-01  2001-09-09  17
8   2001-04-01  2001-10-31  1
```